# How to "vectorize" corrcoeff in matlab?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Since I heard that loops a general bad in matlab, I try to vectorize my code.

I have the following code:

```
for dp_point = 1:useDPs
    cc = corrcoef(Traces(:,dp_point), hws(:,dp_point));
    delta(dp_point) = cc(2);
end;
```

This creates a delta matrix with the size of 1 x useDPs, where useDPs goes up to 1.000.000

It computes the correlation coefficient for each column and saves it in delta, thus its a very long loop and I would like to optimize it for matlab.

What I tried:

```
delta = corrcoef(Traces(:,1:useDPs), hws(:,1:useDPs));
```

But this creates a 2 x 2 matrix (it computes the corr coeff of the whole matrixes, not for each column). So it is obviously a wrong attempt.

So my question is, is it possible to "vectorize" (or otherwise optimize) this loop at all?

Comment: Try it on a small subset and let us know how it goes.

Comment: It might also help to read the docs. For example, type `doc corrcoeff` on the command line.

Comment: What should I try? My "can I write something like that" does obviously not work.

Comment: did you try to run the function call you are asking about? If it takes too long, pass in a smaller data set

Comment: Yes I currently use the first code snipped (and it works as intended). I'm new to matlab and the first code I wrote was "plain c" so now I try to "vectorize" it, so that it works better with matlab. What I don't know is, can this be "vectorized" or is it not possible at all?

Comment: Run the line you yourself proposed: `elta = corrcoef(Traces(:,1:useDPs), hws(:,1:useDPs));`. Just asking if it will run without trying is a waste of everyone's time. I'd be glad to take a look if anything goes wrong and you have trouble figuring it out. Also, keep in mind that while MATLAB is easier to work with, it is unlikely to even come close to a good C implementation in terms of speed.

Comment: I did run it, but it does compute one coefficient matrix and not useDPs coefficient matrices. I tried to say that in the question. It does not do what I want, but is there something simillar that works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129308/discussion-between-pinkie-swirl-and-mad-physicist).

Comment: "I heard that loops a general bad in matlab" →  that doesn't mean it's true.

Comment: Seems so :). But as I said I'm new to matlab and my first code was horrible, then I started to vectorize my loops (it had other loops where the vecotorization worked flawlessly) and got quite the speedup. Since this is a time critical part of my code, I hoped it could be optimized a little better (this runs a LOT faster in c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're problem has only 2 variables, you can write it like this:

```
m = size(X,1);

Xc = bsxfun(@minus, X, sum(X)/m);
Yc = bsxfun(@minus, Y, sum(Y)/m);

xy = sum(Xc.*Yc) / (m-1);
xx = sum(Xc.*Xc) / (m-1);
yy = sum(Yc.*Yc) / (m-1);

delta = xy ./ sqrt(xx.*yy);
```

But, the time I spent on figuring this out, plus this fact:

```
clc

N = 1e4;
M = 1e3;

X = rand(N,M);
Y = rand(N,M);

% Loopy version    
tic
D = zeros(N,1);
for ii = 1:M
    cc = corrcoef(X(:,ii), Y(:,ii));
    D(ii) = cc(2);
end
toc


% "Vectorized" version 
m = N;
tic    

Xc = bsxfun(@minus, X, sum(X)/m);
Yc = bsxfun(@minus, Y, sum(Y)/m);

xy = sum(Xc.*Yc) / (m-1);
xx = sum(Xc.*Xc) / (m-1);
yy = sum(Yc.*Yc) / (m-1);

delta = xy ./ sqrt(xx.*yy);

toc
```

giving

```
Elapsed time is 0.272682 seconds. % loop 
Elapsed time is 0.384599 seconds. % non-loop
```

really shows that *you should not believe* the statement that loops are bad in MATLAB.